# Erro ao executar aplicativo Android - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, build

Criei meu aplicativo pra Android usando react-native.

Consigo utilizar conectando o celular no PC ou utilizando um emulador.

Porém, quando gero a versão assinada do aplicativo e instalo no meu celular ele não roda. Importei o mesmo para o Google Play e baixei no mesmo aparelho que uso pra testar, o mesmo continua não executando e não informa o erro, apenas diz que o "app parou..."

Tem alguma forma de saber qual erro mais específico? Ou uma solução pra isso?

OBS.: Gerei o aplicativo como manda a documentação e o próprio Android Studio, não apresentou erro algum.

[image: Ao executar ele direto do Google Play ou a partir do arquivo .apk]

[image: Nenhum erro ao gerar o .apk]

Comment: Na google play tem uma area com os crashs do app, da uma olhada la, pode ser que ache algo util

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao gerar o build de release (APK de lançamento do app), o procedimento é diferente daquele executado para debug (APK de desenvolvimento). Neste arquivo do print que você enviou, experimente desabilitar as propriedades `minifyEnabled`e `shrinkResources` para o flavour `release`. Isso desativará algumas otimizações que, quando não configuradas corretamente, podem causar travamentos na inicialização do app (que geralmente acontecem por não encontrar recursos, classes ou métodos). Note que do ponto de vista de otimização e, eventualmente segurança (no caso de você desativar alguma opção do ProGuard), estas podem ser opções pouco recomendadas, visto que removem trechos desnecessários (inutilizados) do app a fim de diminuir o tamanho da APK; ou otimizam o código em baixo nível. A documentação relevante está disponível neste [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).

Para descobrir a origem precisa do erro, você pode habilitar as mesmas configurações do flavour `release` para o `debug` - exceto, claro, a propriedade `debuggable`, que deve permanecer `true`. Assim, o processo de build será semelhante e você terá log dos erros logo após o app travar.